# Anchor tag shows wrong styling on dynamic row location

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have a table that is filterable. Row items are anchor tags. The issue is that if the table was currently filtered -> item 3 is clicked -> table filtering removed (all items showing again) -> item 3 is now item 5 in the table -> current item 3 is now highlighed while the actual one that should be is not.

Does anyone know a way around this? I can't use state since it will affect all the anchor tags using that state.

Comment: Are you using redux by chance?

Comment: I am not. The current stack is react/ts/office fabric.